How do I display a logarithmic scale in Material UI Slider
I am making an exposure calculator like the one at https://www.camexcalc.com, but remaking the site in React.JS. I am using the Material UI slider. When I make this slider, it is displaying linearly, but the series is logarithmic, meaning very few numbers on the right and a great density of numbers on the left. How do I override this slider to either be logarithmic scale, or alternatively, to space the values along the scale equidistant as strings without regard to value? Note I am not a React developer this is all very new to me.

const isoValues = [3, 7, 12, 25, 50, 100, 200, 400, 800, 1600, 3200];
const isoMarks = isoValues.map((value) => ({value, label: value.toString()}));
const [iso, setIso] = useState(100);
const handleIsoChange = (event: Event, newValue: number | number[]) => {
    setIso(newValue as number);
};
return(
          <div className="row">
              <div className="col-xs-3 col-sm-2 col-md-4">ISO</div>
              <div className="hidden-xs col-sm-2 col-md-2">
                <label id="IsoDisplay">{iso}</label>
              </div>
              <div className="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-6">
                <Slider
                  className="slider"
                  id="Iso"
                  min = {isoValues[0]}
                  max = {isoValues[isoValues.length - 1]}
                  step={null}
                  value={iso}
                  onChange={handleIsoChange}
                  marks={isoMarks}

                />
              </div>
)

The result is a linear scale with lots of small numbers on the left hand side. I want equidistant spaces between the ISO values

This looks like it was implemented as Scale here: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/16574

https://deploy-preview-30757--material-ui.netlify.app/components/slider/

The code below is a React component with a custom slider that spaces ISO values evenly irrespective of their numeric values.  shadcn/ui was used in creating the slider component which provides more customisation options:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Slider } from '@/components/ui/slider';
import { Label } from '@/components/ui/label';

const ISOSlider = () => {
  // ISO values array
  const isoValues = [3, 7, 12, 25, 50, 100, 200, 400, 800, 1600, 3200];
  
  // Instead of using actual ISO values, we'll use array indices
  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(isoValues.indexOf(100));

  // Convert index back to ISO value
  const currentISOValue = isoValues[selectedIndex];

  const handleSliderChange = (newValue) => {
    setSelectedIndex(newValue[0]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="w-full max-w-md space-y-4">
      <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
        <Label htmlFor="iso-slider" className="text-sm font-medium">
          ISO
        </Label>
        <span className="text-sm font-medium">
          {currentISOValue}
        </span>
      </div>
      
      <Slider
        id="iso-slider"
        min={0}
        max={isoValues.length - 1}
        step={1}
        value={[selectedIndex]}
        onValueChange={handleSliderChange}
        className="w-full"
      />
      
      <div className="flex justify-between text-xs text-gray-500">
        {isoValues.map((value, index) => (
          <span
            key={value}
            className="relative"
            style={{
              position: 'absolute',
              left: `${(index / (isoValues.length - 1)) * 100}%`,
              transform: 'translateX(-50%)'
            }}
          >
            {value}
          </span>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ISOSlider;

How it works:

Instead of using actual ISO values for the slider, we use array indices (0 to 10)
Each index maps to an ISO value in our array
The marks are placed at equal intervals regardless of the actual ISO values
We maintain the actual ISO value in state by mapping the selected index back to the ISO array

Major differences from original code:

We're using indices (0 through 10) as the slider values instead of actual ISO numbers
The slider step is 1 (moving between array indices)
We map the selected index back to get the actual ISO value
The marks are rendered separately below the slider for better control over spacing

This approach ensures that:

All ISO values are spaced equally along the slider
The slider moves discretely between values
The actual ISO value is always correctly displayed

You can modify the styling or positioning to how you want it to look.
I hope this helps.
